# Select2 - write mulitple select into database, double record

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-select2

Interesting problem here.

I am using Select2 to allow the user to fill a select box with multiple values, which are then written into the database table. However, upon inserting the values into the table, I notice that the last value of the select field is always written twice. I suspect a problem with the `foreach` loop, but am not sure how to address this.

The select field is part of modal which after the SAVE button is clicked is sent via AJAX to my ajax.php file, where the insert is handled. The same approach is deployed several times throughout the website without problem, the problem only occurs if its a `multiple` field.

HTML

```
<!-- Department -->
<label>Department Name:</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addDeptName" name="addDeptName" />
</div>
<!-- /.Department -->

<p> </p>

<!-- Positions -->
<label>Department Positions:</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></span>
    <select class="form-control select2" style="width:100%;" id="addDeptPositions" name="addDeptPositions" multiple>
        <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
        <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
        <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
        <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- /.positions -->
```

JS

```
// ADD NEW RECORD TO DATABASE           
$("#NewDepartmentButton").click(function() {
    $("#addDeptName").focus();

    // check that input fields are not empty
    if($("#addDeptName").val()!="" && $("#addDeptPositions").val()!="") {

        $.ajax({
            url: "../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php",
            type: "POST",
            //async: true, 
            data: { action:"new_department",Department_Name:$("#addDeptName").val(),Department_Positions:$("#addDeptPositions").val()}, // form data to post goes here as a json object
            dataType: "html",           

            success: function(data) {
                $('#department_output').html(data); 
                drawVisualization();
            },  
        });
    } else {
        //notify the user they need to enter data
        alert("Please enter a valid Department Name.");
        return;
    }

    // close modal and refresh page
    $('#NewDepartmentModal').modal('hide');
    setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 2000);

    // Reload Datatables
    //$('#department_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();

    // refresh entire website
    //location.reload();

    return;
});
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']=='new_department')) {

    // include connection details
    include 'connect_db.php';

    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $db = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

    //Output any connection error
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $db->connect_errno .') '. $db->connect_error);
    }

    // get variables and sanitize
    $addDeptName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Department_Name']);
    $addDeptPositions = $_POST['Department_Positions'];

    // create new record
    foreach ($addDeptPositions as $c) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `qci_departments` (`Department`,`Positions`) VALUES ('".$addDeptName."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $c)."')";
        $db->query($sql);
    }

    if (!$db->query($sql)) {
        echo "
            <div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissible\">
                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>
                <h4><i class=\"icon fa fa-ban\"></i> Error!</h4>
                There was an error while excuting this query.<br />
                (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error . "
              </div>";
    }

    echo "
        <div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissible\">
            <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class=\"icon fa fa-check\"></i> Alert!</h4>
            Success, record updated successfully. Refreshing database now...
        </div>";

    //close connection
    $db->close();

}
```

Database Result:
eg. if positions "Account Manager" and "Account Receivable Officer" are selected from the multiple field:
[image]

EDIT:
the problem seems related to the array submission since this is what the select value looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => Accounting Manager [1] => Accounts Receivable Officer ) Array ( [0] => Accounting Manager [1] => Accounts Receivable Officer )
```

EDIT 2:
addded a `return;` to the JS code

Comment: print array `$addDeptPositions` and paste it in question. Also paste select2 jquery code if added.

Comment: if you are using select with multiple option, don't you think `name="addDeptPositions"` should be `name="addDeptPositions[]"`

Comment: @HappyCoding when it is directly submitted via a `<form>` element, yes. However, I am submitting via AJAX. If I add a `[]` to the select name, the `$_POST['Department_Positions']` variable is not recognized anymore.

Comment: @RuchishParikh good call, this is the array: `Array ( [0] => Accounting Manager [1] => Accounts Receivable Officer ) Array ( [0] => Accounting Manager [1] => Accounts Receivable Officer )
` it submits the record twice right off the bat. How do I address this?

Comment: we can not address the issue because you have not specify from where form data submitted. From where $_POST['Department_Positions']` fetch.

Comment: please attach ajax code so we can identify.

Comment: Your code seems perfect. Not able to judge without debugging just try once remove `async: true` and check.

Comment: @RuchishParikh same result. what seems funny though is that the array holds both submitted values twice, but only posts the second submitted value twice... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: add return at last line of js code before completed onClick function

Comment: @RuchishParikh done, but no result.

Comment: Tried on my local. Its working fine for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to have been with the AJAX interaction, more specifically with the `mysqli_real_escape()` and the SQL statement.

I changed the `foreach` loop to this and it miraculously worked, although the change consists only of renaming the SQL variable and removing the escape string (which I later added again and still works).

```
// create new record
foreach ($addDeptPositions as $c) {
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `qci_departments` (`Department`,`Positions`) VALUES ('".$addDeptName."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$c)."')";
    $db->query($sql2);
}
```

Not sure why that is, but it works now :)

Comment: You can also add a unique index on the Department field. It will ensure that rows with same value for Department field are not added.